# Windows Form error in Visual Studio Express 2013

Tags: compiler-errors

Complete beginner here with C++ language.

In Win32 project.

I added a **Windows Form** and debugged. Then I received 2 errors saying:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function __tmainCRTStartup
error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I used:

```
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

in "MyForm.cpp" but it still doesn't work.

I try to make a window application for important personal uses.

I don't have "Windows Forms Application" project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using win32 forms, you'll need to learn win32 programming starting with https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559(v=vs.85).aspx which explains that these programs have an entrypoint called WinMain rather than "main".

You can use the VS project wizard and let it fill out a demo application for you to begin with.

Comment: It doesn't show the errors, but I get other errors about syntax. I will look at it later and learn about it.

Comment: There are many tutorials for writing your first Windows Forms application. You can google for them or try https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YR6fxe1wa8g